# Can I define a "not" operator in Python?

Tags: python, oop, operators

I am trying to interface a C++ library that implements logical operators &&, ||, ! (unary operator not) to operate on custom selection classes.

I'm a bit stuck because I can't find an unary 'not' operator in Python. 
Is it possible to override the built in '**not**' operator which works on boolean in Python ?

Is there another suitable operator, or do I need to define a function 'Not()' to implement this behavior?

Comment: you can't overwrite the `not` operator.... cause their implemented in C

Comment: not is unary and will operate on other data types other than boolean in python, what is the motivation behind changing it?

Comment: I would like a low precedence unary operator to use in my program.  The function I need is currently mapped to '~', but that is rather high  precedence and makes expressions messier than they would otherwise need to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot override the **boolean** operators (`and`, `or`, and `not`) with special method hooks, because `and` and `or` operate lazily and a special method would require that you evaluate operands early instead.

You can only influence how the object is evaluated to a boolean (using the [`__nonzero__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) or [`__len__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) methods, depending on whether you are implementing a numeric or container type; Python 3 renamed `__nonzero__` to [`__bool__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__)).

You *can* hook into bitwise operators (`&`, `|` and `~`), with the [`__and__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__and__), [`__or__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__or__), and [`__invert__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__invert__) methods, however. This is probably what you are looking for instead. For `&` and `|` there are also inverse and in-place hooks available ([`__rand__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rand__), [`__ror__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ror__), [`__iand__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iand__) and [`__ior__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ior__)).

The result of the boolean hooks (`__nonzero__`, etc.) are cast to a boolean (`True` or `False`), but the bitwise operator hooks can return anything you like. `~custom_obj` will evaluate to whatever `type(custom_obj).__invert__(custom_obj)` returns; `custom_obj1 & custom_obj2` will return the result of `type(custom_obj1).__and__(custom_obj1, custom_obj2)`, unless that method doesn't exist or returns `NotImplemented`, in which case `type(custom_obj2).__rand__(custom_obj2, custom_obj1)` is called instead.

Comment: Totally nit-picking but I doubt `not` is lazy.

Comment: @MarkRansom: It is indeed not lazy. I was simplifying.

Comment: @Guy: `not`'s behavior is perfectly overridable for a custom object, provided you want to influence if it returns `False` or `True`. That's the full extend of your influence.

Comment: how is `not` really different than C `!` anyway? while this is all interesting, does he really have to do that?

Comment: @Guy: Depends on your project. [SQLAlchemy does it](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.not_), to great effect. Same for using [`|` for `or`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_) and [`&` for `and`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_).

Comment: the guy say he can't find a unary `not` operator in python... he also say that in it's default `not` will only operate on boolean...

Comment: So? And he asks for a better operator, which is `~`. What information are you missing here?

Comment: maybe it's me, but how is `not` not unary in python? or, is `not` really operate only on boolean?

Comment: @Guy: That is not really the issue here, is it? `not` *returns* a boolean always. The wording is just badly chosen. And yes, `not` is a unary operator, but the OP is looking for a unary operator that lets you return something *else*. And that is what I address in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`not` just acts on boolean values in python. If that is sufficient in your use case you can override the [`__nonzero__` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__). Otherwise your stuck to implement your own `obj.inverted()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> hex(~0xaa & 0xff)
'0x55'
```

Just have to use the matching Python operator.